# Correct way of establishing Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I realize questions like this may be confusing and hard to understand, but I'll do my best to explain my problem as detailed as possible.

**What I'm trying to do:** Show all the days a certain theatre play is being performed.

**What I have:** A table with all plays performed so far, and a table with all days (including a foreign key referring to the associated play in each row)

[image]

[image]

Here's how I have established the relationship between the two:

**Days.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Days extends Model
{
    public function play()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plays', 'play_id');
    }
}
```

**Plays.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Plays extends Model
{
    public function days()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Days');
    }
}
```

Then finally, this is how I'm trying to show the associated days in a view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($play->days() as $day)
    <li class="text-center text-muted">{{ $day->day }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**The result I'm getting:** An unordered list without any `<li>` tags, as if there's no days at all.

I've had trouble with Eloquent relationships before, but since this time it's not showing me any errors, I don't know exactly what's wrong.
Also, the way I've passed the *$play* value to the view is correct, since I'm referring to it and asking for its values succesfully many times before in the same file.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Change your classes names to singular nouns (Play, Day) or specify foreign key in hasMany relation. Laravel tries to guess foreign key name from class name, in this case it tries to find days by plays_id key.

Answer (score 1):

**Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties.** 
Try **$play->days** instead of **$play->days()** in loop

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out to be a combination of both sahed and Dmitri's answers:

I specified which foreign key to use in both models, since renaming them in ever location I used them would have taken a very, very long time:

**Plays Model**

```
public function days()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Days', 'play_id');
}
```

**Days model**

```
public function play()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plays', 'play_id');
}
```

Before, I'd only done this in Days, but apparently it needs to be done in both.

Also, removing the brackets fixed the final few problems, so thank you both!